# replace string if line contains another string in gawk

Tags: bash, awk, terminal

Inside a text file, I want to find any line containing **4294967295**

```
<DVAMarker>{"DVAMarker":{"mCuePointList":[{"mKey":"marker_guid","mValue":"4e469eea-d7a9-49e8-b034-a4001272ddfb"},{"mKey":"keywordExtDVAv1_87b5cf3c-5b50-4ceb-8ae4-0978c58d3775","mValue":"{\"color\":4294967295}"}],"mDuration":{"ticks":3911846400000},"mMarkerID":"9c6d9e19-3790-4e25-bd3f-8808f1ce73ea","mName":"Montenegro","mStartTime":{"ticks":88062266880000},"mType":"Comment"}}</DVAMarker>
```

Then insert **mComment":"BLUE",** before **"mCuePointList"**, so the result would look like

```
<DVAMarker>{"DVAMarker":{mComment":"BLUE", "mCuePointList":[{"mKey":"marker_guid","mValue":"4e469eea-d7a9-49e8-b034-a4001272ddfb"},{"mKey":"keywordExtDVAv1_87b5cf3c-5b50-4ceb-8ae4-0978c58d3775","mValue":"{\"color\":4294967295}"}],"mDuration":{"ticks":3911846400000},"mMarkerID":"9c6d9e19-3790-4e25-bd3f-8808f1ce73ea","mName":"Montenegro","mStartTime":{"ticks":88062266880000},"mType":"Comment"}}</DVAMarker>
```

I am using bash and gawk in Terminal on a mac.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is a json or xml(doesn't look to me, though I am not an expert in it), with `awk` if you could try following.

```
awk '/4294967295/{sub(/"mCuePointList"/,"mComment\":\"BLUE\",&")} 1' Input_file
```